# behaviour of dynamic_cast up another chain

Tags: c++

i was just reading this question here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/2689696
and it tells that dynamic cast

> You can use it for more than just casting downwards -- you can cast sideways or even up another chain. The dynamic_cast will seek out the desired object and return it if possible.

**so what does this really mean and what are the limitations/ conditions under which this can happen.**

and i assume this is what the statement means. And the cast happens and i get a segmentation fault too which is obvious.

```
#include <iostream>
class base
{
public:
    virtual void print () = 0;
};

class childa : public base
{
public:
    char c1;
    virtual void print ()
    {
        std::cout << "childa\n";
    }
    void printout()
    {
        std::cout << "childa out\n";
    }
};

class childb : public base
{
public:
    int c2;
    virtual void print ()
    {
        std::cout << "childb\n";
    }
    void printin()
    {
        std::cout << "childb in\n";
    }
    void printout()
    {
        std::cout << "childb out\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    base* b = new childa;
    b ->print();
    dynamic_cast<childa*>(b)->printout();
    dynamic_cast<childb*>(b)->printout();   // cast happens here and the output is printed
    dynamic_cast<childa*>(b)->c1 = 'a';
    dynamic_cast<childb*>(b)->c2 = 2;   // segfault here
}
```

This is the output i get and a segfault occurs

> childa
> childa out
> childb out
>
> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 5.844 s
> Press any key to continue.

EDIT:
Yes it was foolish of me not to check for null value.
but i wanted to know more about the comment from the other question(Up/Down/Sideways)

Comment: `b` does not point to a `childb`, so the cast fails.

Comment: cross-casting occurs when you have: `class base1;` `class base2; /* not related to base1*/` `class derived : public base1, public base2` `base1 * b1instance = new derived; dynamic_cast<base2>(b1instance)`

Essentially, to cross cast you need a pointer to some base, and you dynamically cast it to a pointer to some unrelated base in another heirarchy, but the underlying object actually does derive from both heirarchies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're hitting Undefined Behaviour here:

```
dynamic_cast<childb*>(b)->printout();
```

The cast actually fails (returns a null pointer). You never check the return value and call a member function through it. That's Undefined Behaviour and anything can happen. In your case, it seems that because the function does not access `this` in any way, it executes just fine even though invoked through a null pointer. But that's not guaranteed.

---

As for what a sideways cast (or cast up another chain) is, that needs a more complex inheritance hierarchy to demonstrate:

```
struct base1
{
  virtual ~base1() {}
};

struct base2
{
  virtual ~base2() {}
};

struct child1 : base1
{};

struct child2 : base2
{};

struct both : child1, child2
{};


int main()
{
  child1 *c1 = new both();
  static_cast<base1*>(c1);  // ok
  static_cast<both*>(c1);  // ok
  static_cast<child2*>(c1);  // compile-time error, unrelated types
  dynamic_cast<child2*>(c1);  // succeeds, because the object is actually of type `both`, i.e. derived from `child2`; cast sideways
  static_cast<base2*>(c1);  // compile-time error, unrelated types
  dynamic_cast<base2*>(c1); // succeeds, because the object is actually of type `both`, i.e. derived from `base2`; cast up another chain

  base1 *b1 = new child1();
  static_cast<child1*>(b1);  // ok
  static_cast<both*>(b1);  // compiles, but produces UB, as the object is not of correct type
  static_cast<base2*>(b1);  // compile-time error, unrelated types
  dynamic_cast<base2*>(b1);  // fails (returns null pointer), because the object is not actually derived from `base2`.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast<T*>(a)` returns a not null `T*` if and only if `*a` is instance of `T`; otherwise, it returns `NULL`.

Invoking a method or attribute from a null pointer produces an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The usefulness of dynamic_cast is in his answer. With this code

```
int main()
{
    base* b = new childa;
    b ->print();

    childa* testA = dynamic_cast<childa*>(b);
    if (testA)
    {
        //Here you can be sure that your object is right
        testA->printout();
        testA->c1 = 'a';
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Error casting b to testA" << std::endl;

    childb* testB = dynamic_cast<childb*>(b);
    if (testB)
    {
        //Here you can be sure that your object is right
        testB->printout();
        testB->c2 = 2;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Error casting b to testB" << std::endl;
}
```

you obtain the following output

```
childa
childa out
Error casting b to testB
```