# Does dynamic_cast work even when there is no inheritance?

Tags: c++, c++11

std::bad_cast:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast

> An exception of this type is thrown when a dynamic_cast to a reference type fails the run-time check (e.g. because the types are not related by inheritance)

So, if the types are not related by inheritance then it throws an error, so how it the following quote hold true?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/462608

> You can use it for more than just casting downwards – you can cast **sideways** or even **up another chain**.

What does this quote mean? Please give examples.

Comment: Explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast#Example) -- look for 'sidecast'.

Comment: You should do a bit of research [what is side-cast or cross-cast in Dynamic_cast in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959921/what-is-side-cast-or-cross-cast-in-dynamic-cast-in-c) or [behaviour of dynamic_cast up another chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489333/behaviour-of-dynamic-cast-up-another-chain)

Comment: @t.niese thank you for finding the relevant questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sideways cast would be for example like this:

```
class Base1 { virtual ~Base1() = default; };
class Base2 { virtual ~Base2() = default; };
class Derived: public Base1, public Base2 {};

int main() {
    Base1* p1 = new Derived;
    Base2* p2 = dynamic_cast<Base2*>(p1);
}
```

Types `Base1` and `Base2` are unrelated to each other, but you can cast between the pointers because `Derived` inherits from both.

I'm not sure what did the original answerer mean by "cast [...] up another chain", but I guess they meant a situation where you would have a `Base1*` pointer and would cast to `Base2` parent.

Comment: Your code is actually UB since none of the types is polymorphic.

Comment: I guess that "up another chain" is in a situation involving multiple inheritance and a side cast